# no puedo obtener la variable de un modulo en el archivo app.js (Node.js)

Tags: nodejs

Quiero enviar una variable de un módulo muy sencillo de `svm` (machine learning) al servidor `app.js`, estoy trabajando con **NodeJS**.

Este es mi codigo:

```
'use strict'; 
var so = require('stringify-object'); 
var svm = require('../lib');   
var xor = [
    [[0, 0], 0],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], 0] ];   
// initialize predictor 
var clf = new svm.CSVC({ kFold: 1 });   
clf.train(xor)
    .progress(function(progress){
        console.log('training progress: %d%', Math.round(progress*100));
    })
    .spread(function (model, report) {
        console.log('training report: %s\nPredictions:', so(report));
        xor.forEach(function(ex){
            var prediction = clf.predictSync(ex[0]);
            console.log('   %d XOR %d => %d', ex[0][0], ex[0][1], prediction);
        });
    });
```

Cómo enviar la variable `prediction`?

Lo modifiqué así:

```
'use strict';
var so = require('stringify-object');
var svm = require('../lib');

var xor = [
    [[0, 0], 0],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], 0]
];
var prediction;
// initialize predictor
var clf = new svm.CSVC({
    kFold: 1
});
clf.train(xor)
    .progress(function(progress){
        console.log('training progress: %d%', Math.round(progress*100));
    })
    .spread(function (model, report) {
        console.log('training report: %s\nPredictions:', so(report));
        xor.forEach(function(ex){
            prediction = clf.predictSync(ex[0]);
            console.log('   %d XOR %d => %d', ex[0][0], ex[0][1], prediction);
            prediction="prediciendo desde cbba";
            return {
            prediction:1    
            };
        });
    });
exports.prediction =prediction;
```

Pero no logro mostrar en el `app.js`. La variable llega `undefined`.

Código:

```
var ror = require('./node_modules/node-svm/examples/evaluation-example');
console.log(ror.prediction);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor que exportas se obtiene de manera asincrónica y tu lo estás exportando cuando aún el valor no se ha calculado, de ahí que te llegue como `undefined`.

La solución es exportar en tu módulo una función que acepte callback y enviar en este el valor cuando sea calculado.

```
'use strict';
var so = require('stringify-object');
var svm = require('../lib');

var xor = [
    [[0, 0], 0],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], 0]
];

function prediction(callback) {
  // initialize predictor
  var clf = new svm.CSVC({
    kFold: 1
  });
  clf.train(xor)
    .progress(function(progress) {
      console.log('training progress: %d%', Math.round(progress * 100));
    })
    .spread(function(model, report) {
      console.log('training report: %s\nPredictions:', so(report));
      xor.forEach(function(ex) {
        // No puedes usar la variable prediction 
        // porque ocultarías el nombre de la función
        var pred = clf.predictSync(ex[0]);
        console.log('   %d XOR %d => %d', ex[0][0], ex[0][1], pred);
        // Esto eliminaría el valor por eso lo comento
        //prediction = "prediciendo desde cbba";

        // Invocas el callback con los datos
        callback(null, pred);
        return {
          prediction: 1
        };
      });
    });
}

// Exportas la función
exports.prediction = prediction;
```

Para usarlo debes llamarlo de esta forma

```
var ror = require('./node_modules/node-svm/examples/evaluation-example').prediction;

ror(function(error, prediction) {
    console.log(prediction);
});
```

Esta función será llamada varias veces ya que tu valor de la predicción se encuentra dentro de un ciclo `forEach`.

Si te preguntas porque uso `(error, valor)` lee

http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/

Si no manejas el error simplemente elimina el parámetro.

Comment: sale error: C:\Users\SM\Desktop\proyectosvm\app.js:15
ror(function( prediction) {
^                                                                                                        TypeError: ror is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SM\Desktop\proyectosvm\app.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3

Comment: @rn3w Listo, corregido, me falto referenciar `.prediction` al final del `require`

Comment: no termina de mostrar el resultado por consola realizado por este codigo    console.log('   %d XOR %d => %d', ex[0][0], ex[0][1], pred); antes mostraba asi Predictions:
     0 XOR 0 => 0
     0 XOR 1 => 1
     1 XOR 0 => 1
     1 XOR 1 => 0  y ahora se queda asi:                                              Predictions:
     0 XOR 0 => 0                                                                                               y **aun no muestra por console desde app.js** , ya no hay ningun error, pero no hace lo que quiero

Comment: @rn3w Ups, ya lo corregí :P Me faltó hacer el callback correctamente con `callback(null, pred);` ya que el primer parámetro es el de error.

Comment: @rn3w También la sintaxis de la función es `function prediction(callback)`. La raíz de los errores es que añadí el estilo node después de haber escrito toda la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias, funciono al 100%, tendre que leer mas sobre callback.

Comment: una pregunta, esta funcionando muy bien, pero no entiendo esta parte, return {
          prediction: 1
        }; desde el callback envias el valor 1, pero por consola muestra el valor **var pred = clf.predictSync(ex[0]);**, eso esta bien  pero por que hace eso si envias el valor 1?

Comment: @rn3w No te olvides de votar/marcar como aceptado si te sirvió mi respuesta.

Comment: @rn3w No había leído el comentario anterior. El `return {prediction: 1}` lo copié de tu código original. No tengo la menor idea de lo que hace :P si crees que sobra elimínalo :)